# How to build multiple interdependent Visual Studio solutions in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We have several Visual Studio solutions which have project dependencies between them.

Honouring the project dependencies is easy enough in TFS 2015 where we simply add an ordered list of solutions to the build definition.

However, how is this done in DevOps? I can add the solutions as separate Build tasks in an Azure pipeline, but tasks don't seem to have access to the output of the previous build, and so binary reference errors occur.

Is there a way of stringing the solution builds together so that each build has access to the output of previous builds?

Comment: It is possible to import the artifacts of the preceding builds... (Not sure if that is the best method / practical in all situations though, which is why this is a comment instead of an answer)

Comment: Perhaps having layered solutions is not desirable in the world of microservices? i.e. - each solution should be self-contained and so there is no need to build multiple solutions for a given pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

> How to build multiple interdependent Visual Studio solutions in Azure DevOps

There are many ways to do it, but unfortunately it doesn't have a best answer. Because the best solution is always to have a single repository.

To resolve this issue, you can:

- Add the `.dll` file of dependent project to a the NuGet package. upload to a feed, such as VSTS feed: [Package Management in VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/overview?view=azure-devops), then restore packages during the build (This is the way we are using).
- Add [Download Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task to build definition to download the artifact of previous build. You also can call [Builds REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#get-build-artifacts) through PowerShell to get build artifacts.
- You can consider to use [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) or [Git Subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) if it is Git repository.
- If you are using TFVC repository, you can get the Extensions project by specify additional Workspace mappings in Get Sources section of build definition (Specify it directly, can click … to select)

Hope this helps.

Comment: A single repository with multiple builds (e.g. one per service) suffers from the same issue.

Comment: @GertvandenBerg, Yes, if the referenced project in the another solution, you still have this issue, because VS/MSBuild could not build the project out of current solution. You need to build that referenced project first, then copy dll file to the referencing project bin folder.